# Thieves disguised as clowns rob bank without violence

Tags: identify-this-movie

Around 10 years ago I was traveling to another city in a bus that was playing a movie. I did not see the start of the movie so I do not know its title. It was briefly about thieves disguised as clowns robbing a bank.

They had a genius plan to trick the police and didn't use violence.

I did not see the end because I had to leave the bus since I arrived my destination. I wonder if anyone has any idea about what this movie could be. I really want to know what happened at the end.

The movie was probably from the 90's, in color. I do not know if they were speaking English or not, since it was dubbed in Turkish.

Comment: Hello, clowns robbing a bank is very common, have you got any other details to add to help us identify this movie?

Comment: @M.Polo do you have any guess? The whole movie was about the robbery. There was not any preparation phase, etc. It almost started with the robbery.

Comment: "It was a genius movie." Tell us why.

Comment: @Dannie honestly I cannot remember the details :( But, the way the thieves were dealing with the police was genius. And, there was not much violence as far as I remember.

Comment: @Dannie It was not a dark & violence movie with high tension. I do not remember any shoot-out. They were having a continuous conversation with the police, and they were tricking the police perfectly. No victims were killed.

Comment: Could it be Hold-Up (1985)?

Comment: @Dannie could be, I will check it and will let you know. Thank you so much again!

Comment: ^ I have made a few edits to your question. I have assumed the movie was in color and that they spoke english, please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @Dannie see my correction about `since the audio was converted to Turkish`, I am not sure if I used proper English there.

Comment: Sounds like the beginning of The Dark Knight.

Comment: @HannoverFist - you mean apart from the high levels of violence and lack of tricking the police?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yqvbv-SB4bg The Dark Knight?

Comment: @HannoverFist thanks for the answer dude! but there is no way that someone does not recognize a batman movie :)

Comment: @renakre - that's what I used to think until I saw another ID question today about a kid and his robot friend going to the **star**s to fight in **wars**.

Comment: @HannoverFist What kind of blood festivals do you watch to consider that scene "non-violent"? ;)

Comment: @renakre May be [Der Clown](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0373762/?ref_=kw_li_tt), a German movie from 2005

Answer (score 19):

Sounds awfully like 'Quick Change' (1990), a comedy about 3 friends who rob a bank dressed like clowns and have to escape from the bank and New York City. The film stars and is co - directed by Bill Murray, which could be a bit of a deal - breaker if you cannot recall seeing him in the film.

Both 'Hold Up' & 'Quick Change' are cinematic adaptions of Jay Cronley's graphic novel 'Quick Change' but the first is in French.

'Quick Change' - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100449/

[image]

Comment: Only one robber is dressed as a clown in _Quick Change_.

Comment: I realise that, didn't want to get too specific about the plot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The description reminded me of [Point Break](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102685/).

The bank robbers weren't technically disguised as clowns, but they were wearing masks of past presidents, and the masks were rather clownish-looking.  Despite the guns, they did try to avoid violence in their robberies; they only took money from the cash drawers, and tried to be in-and-out in just a couple minutes.  Point Break was released in 1991.

Does the image below fit with what you remember?

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! I have checked the trailer, but %100 sure not this one.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably 'Inside Man' (2006). Except they weren't disguised as clowns. But they definitely used no violence and had a really tricky plan.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have seen this movie. Not this one :)

Comment: Your efforts are well appreciated. Please note that most responders to this type of question also include a link to the write-up for the movie and/or a clip illustrating the written rationale you gave. I hope you are enjoying it here.

Comment: "Except they weren't disguised as clowns." Considering the question specifically mentioned the movie had clowns, this answer seems ... lacking.

Comment: I do remember that they were masked (and that was a major point in their plan). I didn't realize that they were'n disguised as clowns until I actually found the movie description (on wikipedia).

Comment: and it depends on your view of 'violence' as it relates to Inside Man. Holding people hostage and forcing them to disrobe would count as violence - certainly to the victims